# Quick smoke in blender 2.8 goes the wrong direction

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I tried looking for it everywhere, but I can't seem to find a fix for it. 
Maybe I'm making just some really du b mistake but I can't seem to figure out what that would be. I looked everywhere and made node setups for the fire and smoke but they all had the same problem: the smoke and fire are going to the left instead of going up. Please help it has been very frustrating. [image]

Comment: you have a field effector in the, that is directing the smoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wind force in the scene. If you want that to make the smoke go up, scale the domain, and rotate it parallel to the Z axis. Then bake the smoke at whatever your settings are for it, and your problem should be fixed. This problem was caused because the wind blew the smoke across the top of the domain, not up.

Comment: I have no idea how the wind force got into that project because I never used it there, but creating a new project fixed it for me. Thanks mate